# Get response of ajax when target content loads on document.ready

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mocha.js

Hi i've got an ajax post and the response div i want from the other file will be generated after $document_ready function. But the div show empty string when i alert it. Here's my code

```
 var cekJawaban = function(){
    var form_data={
      kode:$("#code").val(),
      id_materi:$("#idmateri").val(),
      id_user:$("#iduser").val(),
      id_lesson:$("#idlesson").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/ta2/frontpage/cekKode',
      type: 'POST',
      async : true,
      data: form_data,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data){ 
        /*var res = resp;
        if(resp=="true")
        {
          $("#alertsukses").show();
          $("#submit").hide();
          $("#lanjut").show();
        }
        else
        {
          $('#salah').html(resp);
          $("#alertsalah").show();
        }*/
      console.log($(data).find('#mocha').text());
      },
      error: function(xhr) {

      }
    });
    return false;
  };
```

And here's the target url file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery-2.0.3.min.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/expect/jquery.expect.min.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/mocha/mocha.js')?>"></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/mocha/mocha.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<script>mocha.ui('bdd');
mocha.reporter('html');</script>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<?php echo $code; ?>
<div id="cek">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

describe("Index", function () {
    it("Harus punya div",function(){
        fn();
    })
})
mocha.run();

$(document).ready(function(){
    var notif=""
    if($('.error').length>0)
    {
    var err = $('.error').html();
    var sub = err.substr(0,err.indexOf('@'));
    notif=sub;
}
else
{
    notif="pass";
}
$('#cek').text(notif);
});

var fn = function(){
$expect('body').to.exist('Jangan lupa buat body')
.and.to.have.children('p', "Jangan lupa buat p");
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your ajax code contain javascript, you should append to body first so javascript can execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible, javascript is executed on client side and if you're requesting the page by ajax you will get only the static content of it. You must consider to change the work flow of your code and **stick to dynamic content generation of the target url on the server-side code.**

if you pursue this workflow you may get the content and also the javascript code which I think you don't want

Comment: He can append to body and still get it

Comment: you will even get also the javascript code and not only the content

Comment: Nope, when you append to body, javascript will be executed, but you must wait for it to finish before get the content it generate

Comment: Thanks for you answer i get it now. Do you have any information on how can i run the the document function ready then call the response?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your javascript document.ready() function in the "target url file", you can put the javascript code into the success-function of the Ajax call.

So you call the url, the url returns your content, and after content has been returned you can execute javascript code in the success()-function.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/ta2/frontpage/cekKode',
  type: 'POST',
  async : true,
  data: form_data,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data){ 
    //Call your document.ready() here instead.
    var notif=""
    if($('.error').length>0){
        var err = $('.error').html();
        var sub = err.substr(0,err.indexOf('@'));
        notif=sub;
    }
  }
});
```